# Not able to attach the persistent volume to the Prometheus pod installed using helm chart

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, amazon-efs

I have tried to install a cost monitoring tool opencost to our kubernetes cluster using the below mentioned command:

```
helm install my-prometheus --repo https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts prometheus \
  --namespace prometheus --create-namespace \
  --set pushgateway.enabled=false \
  --set alertmanager.enabled=false \
  -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencost/opencost/develop/kubernetes/prometheus/extraScrapeConfigs.yaml
```

(its a prerequisite)

Unfortunately we are not using any pv and pvc, so i have installed a efs driver and it is working properly. And i have created a EFS file system in AWS console and allowed the inbound traffic from security groups of k8's nodes. And created a storage class for efs with filesystem id.

Just for checking weather EFS is working or not, tried to deploy a dummy application. volume is binding.

now the problem is the the prometheus pod is not trying to bind the volume with storageclass i have created for EFS.

It is still trying to use same default gp2 volume.

I have tried adding pvc related code in the values file of Prometheus and also tried to create separate yaml file for pvc..nothing is working

It would be really helpful if anyone help on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome Harshitha to SO, thanks for sharing the details however could you please share the Gitrepo where you are managing the helm or YAML template as it would be hard to guess what you have tried actually. If you have manually created PVC with storageclass can't you attach that to Prom ? what actual error are you facing ?

Answer (score 0):

You must follow these steps:

1.create a StorageClass that points to your AWS EFS service

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/blob/master/examples/kubernetes/dynamic_provisioning/specs/storageclass.yaml

2.create a PersistentVolumeClaim from the StorageClass created in the previous step

(you can take a look here --> https:///stackoverflow.com/questions/46124006/how-to-configure-a-persistent-volume-claim-using-aws-efs-and-readwritemany)

3.add to installation string `--set server.persistentVolume.existingClaim="PVC-NAME"`

Comment: Here you can find all the configuration parameters of the Prometheus Chart:

https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/prometheus/values.yaml